# Java String Split/Manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I need to write a method in Java that can take a String text parameter and an array of String "regexes" parameter that returns an array of Strings.

I want the returned Array to basically do what `String.split` does, but with multiple String regexes and instead of stripping the regex, keep it in the array.

Example:
`Input: "int a=10; a++;"`
`Regexes: "int", ";", "++", "="`
`Output: "int", " a", "=", "10", ";", " a", "++", ";"`

And I tried a few things including the following, none worked

```
public static String[] splitIntoBits(String in, String[] regex)
{
    List<String> bitList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
    {
        int lastIndex=0;
        //Check that character against all regexes
        for(int j = 0; j < regex.length; j++)
        {   
            if(in.substring(i).startsWith(regex[j]))
            {
                bitList.add(in.substring(lastIndex, i));
                lastIndex=i;
            }
        }
    }

    return bitList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: How do you handle overlapping patterns (in other words, where the match is ambiguous)?

Comment: You could create a new ArrayList after each split, capture the String[]s and feed them into the list. then use the List to feed strings into the next phase.

Comment: @durron597 - I would probably handle that with more specific checking for what comes before or after the regex.

Comment: If you are really trying to parse code you will need more than split().

Comment: @peter.murray.rust - what would I need?

Comment: You may also look at Scanner class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method%5Fsummary) but @peter.murray.rust looks resonable

Comment: For code you need a parser such as ANTLR (you'll find it on SO). But writing a parser is complex. There is already an ANTLR parser that parses Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a single regex to match all the regexes in the argument, then use `Matcher.find()` tracking the end index of previous matches with `end()`.

Note: in my code below, I show `Pattern.quote(r)` to handle '++' (which is an invalid regex pattern).  If you are indeed supporting regexes as the argument, just remove the call.

```
    String[] regex = { "int", ";", "++", "=" };
    StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
    for (String r : regex) {
        pattern.append('|').append(Pattern.quote(r));
    }

    String input = "int a=10; a++;";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern.substring(1)).matcher(input);
    // e.g. m = Pattern.compile("int|;|\\+\\+|=").matcher(input);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0 ; m.find() ; i = m.end()) {
        if (i != m.start()) {
            result.add(input.substring(i, m.start()));
        }
        result.add(m.group(0));
    }
    String[] array = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
```